# error with Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, css, web

My structure is like:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <ul>
           <li id="li1" onclick="someJavascriptFunction()">......</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
           <li id="anotherli1">......</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
function getExecJob(execid){
<c:forEach var="exec" items="${execjobList}">
    var index = '${exec.execid}';

    var ele = document.getElementById("execjoblist"+index);
    if('${exec.execid}'==execid){
        ele.style.color='#DF013A';
        <c:set var ="currentExecId" value="${exec.execid}"/>
        <c:set var ="execJob" value="${exec}"/>
    }else{
        ele.style.color='#339';
    }
</c:forEach>
}
```

I have change css style code in the javascript function. Now it's not only this li1, but all lis like "anotherli1" also response to click . if I click on them ,they have color change!

Could anyone please give me some suggestion about what's happening here and how can I solve it?

Comment: @MilkywayJoe - im here to please;  your LI is empty as such, physically clicking on it isn't probably easy.

LI is a List Item - not an Anchor Tag ( aka "links" )

Provide more complete code and I can provide a more complete answer

Comment: Show us the code for `someJavascriptFunction`, we can't really help without it.

Comment: It's not really that empty, I am just giving the similar structure. Sorry about this confusion.

Comment: Do you have multiple `<li>`s with the id `li1`?

Comment: no, everyone has there own id.

Comment: Can you show the *actual* JavaScript that's sent to the browser?

Comment: This is the real javascript i am using.

Comment: No, what I mean was `<c:forEach var="exec" items="${execjobList}">` is not JavaScript.  Can you show the JavaScript that gets actually sent to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("li").click(function() {
      //your_func(this)
       $(this).css('color', 'red');
   });

});
```

This will when you click any li. You can view demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WCJtX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you have `<c:forEach var="exec" items="${execjobList}">` inside your function.

So, in the function, it adds code for each `<li>` not just the one you clicked on.  Each `<li>` will be set to either `#DF013A` or `#339`.